# WSo2 login page from http instead of https

Tags: http, wso2, single-sign-on

I couldn't find how to configure wso2 login page to be accessible via http on wso2 online documentation. 
Please let me know the steps if someone knows how to do the same.

My WSO2 app needs to be behind http server (SSL enabled) anyways, so I think WSo2 will be protected in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new parameter has been added to cater this in the upcoming version and which will be released in another 1-2 months.
But for the time being, it is not possible.

Comment: What is the parameter?  It would be good to record it here for future viewers of the question/answer.

Comment: Property would be EnableHTTPAdminConsole. This is the jira which is the fix has been done. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14055